# как в DateTime указать время?

Tags: c#

как в

```
var time = new DateTime(2021, 9, 1, 10, 00);
```

указать 1 сентября утро 10 часов

Comment: По какому часовому поясу?

Comment: [Оф док](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.8), [конструкторы структуры](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8). Привыкайте читать документацию.

Comment: @AK - я бы добавил "подсказка Visual Studio"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот так:

```
var time = new DateTime( 2021, 9, 1, 10, 0, 0);
```

(я добавил последню цифру - секунды)

Answer (score 2):

Как дополнительный вариант к существующему ответу:

```
var dateTime = new DateTime(2021, 9, 1).AddHours(10);
```

Comment: - по меньшей мере, оригинально!

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netcore-3.1 туда же